# Repeat array date in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I need to repeat an array starting from a date.

An example:

```
start date: 09/20/2016

$ Rounds = array ('evening', 'afternoon', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Rest');

20/09/2016 evening
21.09.2016 afternoon
22.09.2016 morning
23/09/2016 night
24/09/2016 rest
09/25/2016 evening
09.26.2016 afternoon
09.27.2016 morning
....
```

I have this old script, help me to improve it further rather than print the example. 20/09/2016, it would make a json array, so you can then use with the plugin jquery fullcalendar

```
$data = '03/10/2014';
$turni = array('sera','pomeriggio','Mattina','Notte','Riposo');

$n_g_mesi = array(1=>31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
list($gg,$mm,$aa) = explode('/', $data);
$gg = (int)$gg;
$mm = (int)$mm;
$n_g_q_mese =  $n_g_mesi[$mm];

$numero_turni = 10;

$n = count($turni);
for($i=0; $i<$numero_turni; $i++) {
    echo $data.' '.$turni[$i%$n]."<br />\n";
    $gg = $gg%$n_g_q_mese+1;

    if($gg==1) {
        $mm = $mm%12+1;
        if($mm==3 && $aa%4==0 && $n_g_q_mese==28) { // se l'anno è bisestile
            $mm = 2;
            $gg = $n_g_q_mese = 29;
        }
        else {
            $n_g_q_mese = $n_g_mesi[$mm];
            if($mm==1)
                $aa++;
        }
    }
    $data = str_pad($gg,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'/'.str_pad($mm,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'/'.$aa;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a solution:

```
$aDate = '2016-09-20';
$rounds = array('Evening', 'Afternoon', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Rest');
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $nextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($aDate)));
    echo "\n<br>" . $nextDate . " " . $rounds[$i%count($rounds)];
    $aDate = $nextDate;
}
```

Output:

```
2016-09-21 Evening 
2016-09-22 Afternoon 
2016-09-23 Morning 
2016-09-24 Night 
2016-09-25 Rest 
2016-09-26 Evening 
2016-09-27 Afternoon 
2016-09-28 Morning 
2016-09-29 Night 
2016-09-30 Rest 
2016-10-01 Evening 
2016-10-02 Afternoon 
2016-10-03 Morning 
2016-10-04 Night 
2016-10-05 Rest 
2016-10-06 Evening 
2016-10-07 Afternoon 
2016-10-08 Morning 
2016-10-09 Night 
2016-10-10 Rest
```

Comment: your code works great, the only problem that starts the next day. Example given initial 2010/10/01 your code 2010/10/02

Comment: You may fix starting date like this: $aDate = '2016-09-20'; $aDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($aDate)));

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, to demonstrate some alternative ways of handling dates and arrays in PHP:

```
<?php

$dataString = "03/10/2014";
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat("!m/d/Y", $dataString);

$turni = ["Sera", "Pomeriggio", "Mattina", "Notte", "Riposo"];

$numeroTurni = 10;

foreach (range(1, $numeroTurni) as $i) {
    printf("%s %s<br />\n", $data->format("Y-m-d"), current($turni));
    if (!next($turni)) {
        reset($turni);
    }
    $data->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```

Output:

```
2014-03-10 Sera<br />
2014-03-11 Pomeriggio<br />
2014-03-12 Mattina<br />
2014-03-13 Notte<br />
2014-03-14 Riposo<br />
2014-03-15 Sera<br />
2014-03-16 Pomeriggio<br />
2014-03-17 Mattina<br />
2014-03-18 Notte<br />
2014-03-19 Riposo<br />
```